# What are the *undesirable* effects of windowing in Fourier space?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, window-functions

My goal is to split a periodic signal into two (or more) signals. The first signal would contain the low-frequency information, and the later signals, the higher-frequency information. These signals would then be passed to separate ML models.

Suppose I have a one-dimensional signal $x$ of length $n$, which I write as

\begin{align}
x &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{F}(x)\right) \\
&= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(I\mathcal{F}(x)\right).
\end{align}

Then, I can write matrix $I$ as a sum of diagonals $I_1, \dots, I_n$, where $I_k$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with $1$ in the $(k, k)$ position and $0$s everywhere else:
$$I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ \dots +
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Continuing from above, we have
\begin{align}
x &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(I\mathcal{F}(x)\right) \\
&= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(((I_1 + \dots + I_{n/2}) + (I_{n/2+1} + \dots + I_{n}))\mathcal{F}(x)\right) \\ 
&= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((I_1 + \dots + I_{n/2})\mathcal{F}(x)\right) + \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((I_{n/2+1} + \dots + I_{n})\mathcal{F}(x)\right) \\
&= x_1 + x_2.
\end{align}

The question is: in the discrete setting, are there any *undesirable* effects of windowing in Fourier space in this way? Will the equality always hold? Is Gibbs' phenomenon a problem here?

What about other types of windowing in Fourier space? For example:
$$I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.67 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.33 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.33 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.67 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Edit: Adding some code to show what I am doing.

```
## Initial signal x
x = X[0] 
## Split x in two parts
x1_fft = np.zeros_like(np.fft.rfft(x))
x2_fft = np.zeros_like(np.fft.rfft(x))
## Keep only the first 20 frequencies in x1, and the rest in x2
x1_fft[:20] = np.fft.rfft(x)[:20]
x2_fft[20:] = np.fft.rfft(x)[20:]
## New signals x1 and x2
x1 = np.fft.irfft(x1_fft)
x2 = np.fft.irfft(x2_fft)

## Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 5))

ax[0].plot(x, label='x', alpha=0.5, color='black')
ax[0].plot(x1, label='x1', alpha=0.5, color='blue')
ax[0].plot(x2, label='x2', alpha=0.5, color='skyblue')
ax[0].plot(x1+x2, label='x1+x2', alpha=0.5, color='red', linestyle='--')
ax[0].legend()
ax[0].set_title('x and x1+x2')

ax[1].plot(np.abs(x - x1), label='x1', alpha=0.5, color='blue')
ax[1].plot(np.abs(x - (x1+x2)), label='x1+x2', alpha=0.5, color='red', linestyle='--')
ax[1].legend()
ax[1].set_yscale('log')
ax[1].set_title('Absolute error')

plt.show()
```

[image]

From this, it seems that $x = x_1 + x_2$. Here, I repeat the same experiment with 4 splits (`[0:20], [20:40], [40:60], [60:]`):

[image]

Again, it seems that $x = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Not to flip here, but in essence you found complicated way of doing nothing. As long as the individual matrices add up to the Identity matrix, there are no "undesirable" effects since there are no effects at all.

The more common way of writing a "windowing operation" in the discrete frequency domain is simply element-wise multiplication with a window vector, i.e.

$$Y[k] = W[k] \cdot X[k] \tag{1}$$

The effect in the time domain depends on the type of Fourier Transform being used. For the Discrete Fourier Transform it's circular convolution and for the continuous Fourier Transform is linear convolution, aka as "filtering".

So basically this is just a different way for expressing a filtering operation with the added complexity of circular convolution for the DFT. What effects this has depends really on the type of filter you are using. Assuming you are applying a filter for a specific reason, some of the effects will be desirable and others will not but this will depend specifically on your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to split a periodic signal into two (or more) signals. The first signal would contain the low-frequency information, and the later signals, the higher-frequency information. These signals would then be passed to separate ML models. From your answer, I understood that my method works as intended—is that correct?

Comment: No, it won't work: because of the periodic nature of the DFT you will get time-domain aliasing unless you deploy overlap add convolution. Your problem can easily be solved in the time domain using a lowpass and a highpass filter or a "crossover".

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer then. Is that supposed to be "unless you deploy overlap *and* convolution"? If I do a lowpass and highpass filter, will the sum of the two filtered signals equal the original signal?

Comment: The standard algorithm for frequency  domain LTI filtering is called "overlap add". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method. Whether a lowpass and highpass add up to the original depends on the specific filter design. 1st order IIR filters do. Linear phase filters do as well but with a bulk delay. Odd order Butterworth or Linkwitz Riiley filters add up to an allpass (flat magnitudes response but some phase distortion). There are plenty of other variants, so the best choice depends in your specific application

Comment: I updated my question with some code and plots to show what my method is doing. It seems that no information is lost or gained in the splitting process, so I don't understand where the *time-domain aliasing* comes from.

Comment: It only works as long as you don't change the spectra. If you do some actual processing it will break.

Comment: @user572780 Yes, provided this is only decomposing the $I$ matrix, this is "much ado about nothing".  Once any of the frequency domain coefficients are changed, the circular convolution (time domain aliasing) that Hilmar notes comes into play. See [this reference answer on meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1821/80) for more details.